# Jasmine how to mock http request (for fetch and XMLXtthpRequest)

Tags: http, webpack, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test some ajax function that makes a request to the some url. I tried to use  *nock* to mock http but it it's working because I use Karma runner and it throws to me an error about "can't find module 'fs'". It is because karma run tests on the browser.

How I can do that ? Thanks (I tried  **jasmine-ajax**   but it's also isn't working somehow).

As I understand an issue appears because karma works in the browser. But how I can fight with that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jasmine-ajax surely does work. here is a sample from working code  (jasmine over karma):

```
describe('RequesterTest', function(){

    beforeEach(function(){
       jasmine.Ajax.install(); // this enables interception
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        jasmine.Ajax.uninstall(); // disables interceptions
    })

    it('makes $.ajax', function(){
        spyOn($, 'ajax');
        $.ajax({url: 'http://example.com'});
        expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('assert success callback for ajax', function(){
        spyOn($, 'ajax');
        var myCallback = function(){};
        $.ajax({url: 'http://example.com', success: myCallback});
        var actualAjaxOptions = $.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
        expect(actualAjaxOptions).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
            success: myCallback,
        }));
    });
});
```

exapmle assumes jquery defined globally and no modules/AMD usage.

Comment: Thank you xmlike for your answer. But I did some mistake in the explanation. I am using  **fetch**  instead standard **xmlhttp**. So that's why jasmine-ajax isn't working.  I am tried to use fetch-mock  but it is also doesn't work.

Comment: sorry to miss the point on `fetch`. afair this method returns a promise so you  might just create some kind of wrapper around it so you can mock it and mock a promise returned. might be a bit straitforward but works ))

Comment: Yeah) you are absolutely right :) I think it's a best idea, and all possible solutions based on that concepts. So we should use it till we have an another "complex" solution.